# How to display a image full screen on my second monitor (ubuntu system) using Python

Tags: python, image, ubuntu, monitor

I am using ubuntu system and connected with two monitors (primary and second). How can I display an image full screen on the second monitor using Python or shell command. For example, command

```
eog --fullscreen --display=:0 image.jpg
```

can display image.jpg full screen, but it is only on the primary monitor.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with Python? Why not just do `eog --fullscreen --display=:1 image.jpg`?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that would be to use a program other than eog that supports the geometry flag. For example [feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/). Then assuming you have two 1920x1080 monitors, and your primary monitor is set on the left you could use the command

```
feh --geometry WxH+1920+0 image.jpg
```

where W is the width of the window that will display the image and H is the height. 1920 is the horizontal offset and 0 is the vertical offset.

The answer above assumes that you have the two monitors set in xinerama mode (You can move windows between the two monitors). If you have set up the two monitors as two different X displays then you can use the eog `--display`  flag of eog with the appropriate display number instead.